# New Aptana install + CFEclipse dependency fail. org.eclipse.ui.browser Where can I get archive version of CFEclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3, cfeclipse

I'm trying to do a new install for a co-worker of Aptana with CFEclipse. However the cfeclipse update is failing due to a dependency.

My working system is: Aptana 3.4.2, Eclipse 3.7.2, and CFEclipse 1.4.5.

The new system is trying to install CFEclipse 1.4.6, and failing due to org.eclipse.ui.browser dependency.

Is there somewhere I can get CFE 1.4.5 and load it from local?

Error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: CFEclipse (including MXUnit and Frameworks) 1.4.6.R201403180646 (org.cfeclipse.cfml.feature.feature.group 1.4.6.R201403180646)

Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610)

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Browser Support 3.4.100.v20130527-1656 (org.eclipse.ui.browser 3.4.100.v20130527-1656)
    Browser Support 3.3.101.v20111019-1723 (org.eclipse.ui.browser 3.3.101.v20111019-1723)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 RCP 3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm (com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group 3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm)

```
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q]
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610)
    To: com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group [3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CFML Plug-in 1.4.6.R201403180646 (org.cfeclipse.cfml 1.4.6.R201403180646)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.ui.browser [3.4.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CFEclipse (including MXUnit and Frameworks) 1.4.6.R201403180646 (org.cfeclipse.cfml.feature.feature.group 1.4.6.R201403180646)
    To: org.cfeclipse.cfml [1.4.6.R201403180646]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.browser [3.3.101.v20111019-1723]

Comment: You might need Eclipse 3.8.x, even though that's already out of date and unsupported.

Comment: I'm installing Aptana, not Eclipse. Aptana includes some subset of Eclipse 3.7 as part of the installation. I don't know if / how that could be changed.